# Robot - how to check if the execution of a jar is finished

Tags: java, process, robotframework

I would like to run a jar file using a robot framework test suite, because this test-case is to be included among other test cases.

When the jar is run from the cmd, it produces the expected output, which can take 10 minutes, and then it ends.

My issue is that I'm not capable to detect when the execution of the jar is finished. I tried several keywords combination, in the last attempt I used the keyword Process Should Be Stopped, as shown below, and the result is that the process is always running.

One of my doubts is: which process is running, java? or the execution of the jar?

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
Library    OperatingSystem
Suite Setup    log    running on ${properties.hostname}    
Suite Teardown    Terminate All Processes    kill=True

Variables    C:/Users/theUser/Desktop/CheckOutRegression/Regression/RegressionScripts/config/properties.py

*** Test Cases ***
Check jar execution
    ${data}=    Start Process    java    -jar    da-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    importFile1.json    importFile2.zip    cwd=${properties.pathToScripts}    alias=myProc
    ${wait}=    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10x    60s    Process Should Be Stopped    myProc
    Log    ${wait}  
    ${result}=    Get Process Result    myProc
    Log    ${data.stdout}
```

Do you know how I can check that the execution of the jar file is finished?

Comment: Have you tried waiting long than 10 minutes? You say it can take ten minutes, is it possible it's taking 10 minutes plus a few more seconds? Just to prove whether or not the keyword is working, try having it wait for 15 or 20 minutes.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the standard Process keyword [Wait For Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Wait%20For%20Process)?

Comment: Answer to @Brian Oakley,
yes I did tried with larger time intervals. I also know that the jar was executed, because I've made it, I ran it several times using the cmd, so I know how long it takes. Also, when testing its execution with robot, I verified in the ui with which the jar interacts, that the actions were already done, although in Robot framework the result is that the process is still running.

Comment: @A. Kootstra. Yes I did.
I redone the test using Wait For Process with a difference, importing only the json file.
**It worked.**
When I added again the zip file to be imported **it didn't worked**. When a zip file is imported the http request results in another flow. There is a time that cmd has only the cursor flashing waiting (this is the difference), let's call it point A, but after the process is ended. 
In the Message Log of the latter case, only the output until point A is saved, the rest is not.
In latter it appears Robot does not detect the end of the process or its continuity.